# Redirect if file does not exists to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a super basic redirect request I like to get done, but i mess it up every time i give it a try, the best so far results in a double www.www redirect (http://www.www.domain.tld/)

My .htaccess has 'two' rules i like to get checked and done.

1st: Redirect all non existent files to the root folder

2nd: Add www. if domain requested as non-www

```
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L]

#Rewrite for non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/? [R=301,L]
```

I have changed the first Ruleset, but never worked out

No. 1

```
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L]
```

Ended with a redirectloop

No. 2

```
# If requested resource exists as a file or directory go to it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /? [L]
```

Ended like no rule was even given.. so an error 404 site with the unchanged URL http://www.domain.tld/123456789.html

Where am i going the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `http://` while doing silent rewrite otherwise `mod_rewrite` will convert that to an external redirect. Have your rules like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

#Rewrite for non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# If requested resource is not a file or directory then redirect to /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L,R=302]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: It shows me now the Content, so far the redirect is working! But It keeps its URL again http://www.domain.tld/1234_item.html Modified your code to `# Else rewrite requests for non-existent resources to /index.php
RewriteRule . /? [L]` but that also didn't helped, same result, with cleared cache and in my default proxy .. Redirects are really something that hates me

Comment: Yes, correct. I didn't knew there was something else than that.

Comment: WOW! The code is barely changed and still it works perfectly!!! What a few changes can modify a result. Sorry for not being precise enough in my question. Bookmarked and kept in mind for duture needs :)