# htaccess not working on website hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I will make this super easy to understand.

On my current pc(home), I have xampp installed and all my files are placed in the root folder.  In the root folder, I have an .htaccess file that looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php/user.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Now, I signed up with a host and I copied my whole website and database and everything is perfect except for the htaccess.  It doesn't redirect me to profile.php when I type the persons name after the address link

For example: www.website.com/USERNAME

I don't know why it's not working when it works perfectly at home.

The host i'm using is awardspace

On the host, they don't allow you to place your folder in www/ but rather it's like a subdomain like www/folder/yourwebsite

I dont know if thats the problem

Comment: First of all, check with your hoster whether they _allow_ you to use mod_rewrite, resp. provide that module. The code is conveniently wrapped into an if condition that simply makes it do nothing, if the module is not present.

Comment: Are u sure for this: /profile.php/user.php?id=$1 ? I mean profile.php or user.php, why both? Can you try to remove first slash before profile.php?

Comment: Just check whether .htaccess file exists in server?

Comment: @ZlatkoHristov I still get same error "500 Internal Server Error" and I don't know how to check if it exists in the server.

Comment: They have a htaccess creator but i tried so many combinations and nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't even know how to explain.

I just googled "rewrite if not in root(htaccess)" and copy pasted this whole thing

The first answer here: [Redirect if file does not exists to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755178/redirect-if-file-does-not-exists-to-root)

Modified the directory index to my profile and it worked.  5 freaking hours of searching finally complete.  I was about to go to sleep if this last attempt didnt work.